# Play by these rules, however broken, or create new ones

Tags: logic, fallacies, argumentation

Example,

A: The rules are unfair, you see, only privileged few are getting the benefit.
B: I don't see anything wrong with that. Either create new rules, or hustle through these and be like them.

**What do we call this fallacy?**

Comment: [False dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma).

Comment: Also related to [ergo decedo](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergo_decedo) and [irrelevant conclusion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrelevant_conclusion)

Comment: I don't get the problem, isn't "the rules are unfair" equivalent to "we should create new, more fair rules"?